# Integral or Closed form expression for $\int^\infty_r \left( 1-\frac{1}{1 + Av^{-\alpha}} \right)v \, dv$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, closed-form

How can I find the integral of (or closed form expression for) the following

$$\int^\infty_r \left( 1-\frac{1}{1 + Av^{-\alpha}} \right)v \, dv$$

where $A$ and $\alpha$ are some constants.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\alpha>2$, $A>0$, and $r>0$, then
\begin{align}
\int^\infty_r \left( 1-\frac{1}{1 + Av^{-\alpha}} \right)v \, dv&=\int^\infty_r \frac{v}{(\frac v{A^{1/\alpha}})^{\alpha} + 1} \, dv\\
&=A^{2/\alpha}\int^\infty_{r/A^{1/\alpha}} \frac{t}{t^{\alpha} + 1} \, dt\tag{$t=\frac v{A^{1/\alpha}}$}\\
&=A^{2/\alpha}F(\frac r{A^{1/\alpha}})
\end{align}
where
$$F:x\mapsto\int^\infty_x \frac{t}{t^{\alpha} + 1} \, dt$$
which cannot be simplified except some special $\alpha$.

Answer (score 4):

Continuing on from where @Aforest left off, the integral
$$F(x) = \int_x^\infty \frac{t}{t^\alpha + 1} \, dt,$$
can be expressed in terms of the [incomplete Beta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function#Incomplete_beta_function) $\text{B}(x;a,b)$, namely
$$\text{B}(x;a,b) = \int_0^x t^{a - 1} (1 - t)^{b - 1} \, dt,$$
as follows. Enforcing a substitution of $t \mapsto t^{1/\alpha}$  gives
$$F(x) = \frac{1}{\alpha} \int_{x^\alpha}^\infty \frac{t^{\frac{2}{\alpha} - 1}}{t + 1} \, dt.$$
If we next enforce a substitution of $1 + t \mapsto \dfrac{1}{t}$ one has
$$F(x) = \frac{1}{\alpha} \int_0^{\frac{1}{x^\alpha + 1}} t^{-2/\alpha} (1 - t)^{2/\alpha - 1} \, dt = \frac{1}{\alpha} \text{B} \left (\frac{1}{x^\alpha + 1}; 1 - \frac{2}{\alpha}, \frac{2}{\alpha} \right ),$$
an expression for $F(x)$ in terms of the incomplete Beta function.

Comment: Note that $\int \frac{t^a}{t+1} dt$ is writable in terms of the [Lerch Phi function](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=ddt+t%5Ew+Lerchphi%28t%2C1%2Cw%29)